# How to assign JUnit test resolution in Jenkins/Sonar?

Tags: java, testing, junit, jenkins, sonarqube

We are a team who develop a software written in Java. We use JUnit for unit tests. We would like to find a plugin for Jenkins/Sonar to monitor the results of unit tests.
The aim is to know which test is broken and to be able to assign its resolution to someone.

For exemple you can do it easily with sonar for code review : http://www.sonarsource.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/CreatingReview.png
We are looking for something for Unit tests. We can pay for the software/plugin.

Thanks you for your help

Sylvain

Comment: Isn't this what an issue tracker should be used for? I'm afraid that you are going to mix up responsibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sonar, you can activate the rule "Failed unit tests" ([see it on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/rules_configuration/index/73?searchtext=failed&plugins%5B%5D=common-java&priorities%5B%5D=&rule_status=&commit=Search)): it will generate a violation in Sonar when there's a test failure, and you will be able to assign this violation to somebody.

Note that we also advise to activate the rule "Skipped uni tests" ([see it on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/rules_configuration/index/73?searchtext=skipped&plugins%5B%5D=common-java&priorities%5B%5D=&rule_status=&commit=Search)) to make sure that a failing test is not just skipped to make things green.